# Git-Hook post_commit not printing GIT_DIR environment to log

Tags: githooks

## Debugging git-hooks

Why is `$GIT_DIR` not printed to the log?

```
#Content of githookTest.sh 
foo=~/tmp/foo 
rm -rf $foo
mkdir -p $foo
cd $foo 
git init 
printf "logger 'foo was committed from:' $GIT_DIR" >> .git/hooks/post-commit
sudo chmod +x .git/hooks/post-commit  
touch $foo/bar
git add .
git commit -m "Testmessage"
journalctl -b --grep 'foo was committed from:'
```

Output from upper script

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/tmp/foo/.git/
[master (root-commit) 6c16412] Testmessage
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 bar
-- Logs begin at Sat 2019-06-29 11:02:45 CEST, end at Mon 2020-05-04 09:53:18 CEST. --
May 04 09:53:18 x user[5892]: foo was committed from:
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding

```
export GIT_DIR=${GIT_DIR-`git rev-parse --git-dir`}
```

as top line in `post-commit` solves my problem